Find Font with strike through and delete row
I am trying to find any cell on active sheet and delete its entire row. Does anyone have suggestions
function fontLine() { var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); var rows = sheet.getDataRange(); var numRows = rows.getNumRows(); var values = rows.getValues();

var rowsDeleted = 0; for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {

var row = values[i];

for (var i = 0; i < fontLines.length; i++) { for (var j = 0; j < fontLines[i].length; j++) { if (fontLines[i][j] === 'line-through') > -1 { sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted); rowsDeleted++; }

} };

Trying to execute a command to find text with strike through and delete it entire row

The variable fontLines has not been declared in the included code. Please add a [mcve].

Copy of Finding text with strikethrough and delete its entire row. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

Use getFontLines()
I tried another approach with the same logic given in the problem.

Sample Code
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var dataProperties = dataRange.getFontLines();
  var out = dataProperties.map((x,i)=>x.includes('line-through')?i+1:"")
  for(var i = out.length; i >= 0; i--){
    if(out[i]) ss.deleteRow(out[i]);
  }
}

I used map where we loop each iteration and filter using includes if it has line-through and filter to remove the cells that don't have text strikes.
Before

After

Reference:

map()


Sidenote: Using map instead of forEach in the last line(where you don't intend to use the returned values) is a Antipattern

Thank you for the insights @TheMaster, I already updated the code above.

Removing a row can cause subsequent rows to move up. Therefore, it's essential to iterate through the rows in descending order.
function removeRows() {
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Replace with your sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var flVals = sheet.getDataRange().getFontLines(); 

  for (var i = flVals.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 0; j < flVals[i].length; j++) {
      var cellFL = flVals[i][j];
      // console.log(cellFL)
      if (cellFL == "line-through") {
        sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
        break; // Move to the next row if a strikethrough cell is found
      }
    }
  }
}


Hmm... this will run very slowly because it calls Range.getCell() and Range.getFontLine() separately for every cell. Use Range.getFontLines() and iterate the 2D format array to speed it up.

@doubleunary Thanks for your comment. I've updated the code.

The above code takes forever then times out...any ideas?

Awesome, The edited version appears to work....Thank you very much @taller

From Finding text with strikethrough and delete its entire row:
Use Array.some(), like this:
function deleteRowsWithStrikeThroughInAnyCell() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let numRowsDeleted = 0;
  ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getFontLines().forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
    if (row.some(format => format === 'line-through')) {
      sheet.deleteRows(rowIndex + 1 - numRowsDeleted);
      numRowsDeleted += 1;
    }
  });
  ss.toast(`Deleted ${numRowsDeleted} rows.`);
}

See Array.some().
